# How do I speed up this for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I am using Selenium to scrape a website which has 1500 projects, each with between 2000 and 8000 sub pages that I need to get data from. The data on these pages is dynamically loaded. The amount of information of each page is not the same because the systems were updated over time. This means I need to get all the information with a broad selector and loop through to see if the information is actually there. Often around 100-150 of the first entries are empty but it is not consistent. The output from the CSS selector is around 386 positions long. I am only looking for 23 outputs that may or may not be there depending on the page. Currently the for loop takes around 180s. Is there a faster way to do this?

```
selector_title = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('td')            
incident_type_number = 0
time_start = time.perf_counter() 
for k in range(len(selector_title)):
    if selector_title[k].text == 'Actual status:':
        data_frame_main_call_screen.iat[j,0] = str(selector_title[k+1].text)
    elif selector_title[k].text == 'Stopped:':
        data_frame_main_call_screen.iat[j,1] = str(selector_title[k+1].text)
    elif selector_title[k].text == 'Operational hours to next service:':
        data_frame_main_call_screen.iat[j,2] = str(selector_title[k+1].text)
    elif selector_title[k].text == 'Operating hours:':
        data_frame_main_call_screen.iat[j,3] = str(selector_title[k+1].text)
    elif selector_title[k].text == 'Actual elec. produced:':
        data_frame_main_call_screen.iat[j,4] = str(selector_title[k+1].text)
    elif selector_title[k].text == 'Alarm state:':
        data_frame_main_call_screen.iat[j,5] = str(selector_title[k+1].text)
    elif selector_title[k].text == 'Forced standby:':
        data_frame_main_call_screen.iat[j,6] = str(selector_title[k+1].text)
    elif selector_title[k].text == 'Load level:':
        data_frame_main_call_screen.iat[j,7] = str(selector_title[k+1].text)
    elif selector_title[k].text == 'Storage level::':
        data_frame_main_call_screen.iat[j,8] = str(selector_title[k+1].text)
    elif selector_title[k].text == 'Oil pressure:':
        data_frame_main_call_screen.iat[j,9] = str(selector_title[k+1].text)
    elif selector_title[k].text == 'Smartstarter board temp.:':
        data_frame_main_call_screen.iat[j,10] = str(selector_title[k+1].text)
    elif selector_title[k].text == 'Boiler released:':
        data_frame_main_call_screen.iat[j,11] = str(selector_title[k+1].text)
    elif selector_title[k].text == 'Control panel antenna signal:':
        data_frame_main_call_screen.iat[j,12] = str(selector_title[k+1].text)
    elif selector_title[k].text == 'Control panel PCB temp.:':
        data_frame_main_call_screen.iat[j,13] = str(selector_title[k+1].text)
    elif selector_title[k].text == 'Control panel PSU Voltage:':
        data_frame_main_call_screen.iat[j,14] = str(selector_title[k+1].text)
    elif selector_title[k].text == 'PU UPS accumulator:':
        data_frame_main_call_screen.iat[j,15] = str(selector_title[k+1].text)
    elif selector_title[k].text == 'PU PCB temp.:':
        data_frame_main_call_screen.iat[j,16] = str(selector_title[k+1].text)
    elif selector_title[k].text == 'Heat Distributor, PCB temp.:':
        data_frame_main_call_screen.iat[j,17] = str(selector_title[k+1].text)
    elif selector_title[k].text == 'Flowmaster PSU voltage:':
        data_frame_main_call_screen.iat[j,18] = str(selector_title[k+1].text)
    elif selector_title[k].text == 'Flowmaster pcb temp.:':
        data_frame_main_call_screen.iat[j,19] = str(selector_title[k+1].text)
    elif selector_title[k].text == 'Surge protector:':
        data_frame_main_call_screen.iat[j,20] = str(selector_title[k+1].text)
    elif selector_title[k].text == 'Smartstarter last error.:':
        data_frame_main_call_screen.iat[j,21] = str(selector_title[k+1].text)
        incident_start_index = k+2

    data_frame_main_call_screen.iat[0,22]=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="callInfo"]').text[0:10]
    data_frame_main_call_screen.iat[0,23]=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="callInfo"]/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td').text
```

Here is an example of the output from the dataframe. Only 3 of the columns are shown here

```
Actual status:  Stopped:    Operational hours to next service:
```

0   40 ,Stand-by Last rejected start reason: HEAT ON THE STORAGE    3 hours 58 minutes  3669 hours
1   10 ,Normal operation    3673 hours
2   40 ,Stand-by Last rejected start reason: HEAT ON THE STORAGE    0 hours 27 minutes  3680 hours
3   40 ,Stand-by Last rejected start reason: HEAT ON THE STORAGE    2 hours 2 minutes   3685 hours

Comment: Seems like you have dataframe, if possible, add few rows from the dtaframe and also show what the expected output should look like.

Comment: Use a dictionary, mapping the text to the number, then once `data_frame_main_call_screen.iat[j, your_dict[selector_title[k].text]] = …`.

Comment: I'm struggling to get the dataframe to shown properly I hope it gives an idea though?

Comment: The loop itself is almost certainly not what's taking so long (though it could definitely be refactored for other reasons). How much data do you download from the site? How quickly does the site allow you to fetch that much data?

Comment: Each page is about 2kB of data. I don't know how long it takes to get the data from the website. This would be {selector_title = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('td')} right? If it is that piece of the code it is very quick (less than half a second). When timing various parts of the code, the start to end of the for loop is what is taking by far the longest at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two suggestions for speeding up the loop, specifically:

1. A dictionary lookup is more pythonic, and often faster, than a long if-elif tree.
2. Assigning a method/property call to a local variable [is usually faster](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Loops) than having to look it up for every iteration of the loop. I'm thinking here specifically of the fact that you're repeatedly calling the property `.iat` on your DataFrame instance.

Consider doing this:

```
lookup_table = {
    string: i for i, string in enumerate((
        'Actual status:',
        'Stopped:',
        'Operational hours to next service:',
        'Operating hours:',
        'Actual elec. produced:',
        'Alarm state:',
        'Forced standby:',
        'Load level:',
        'Storage level::',
        'Oil pressure:',
        'Smartstarter board temp.:',
        'Boiler released:',
        'Control panel antenna signal:',
        'Control panel PCB temp.:',
        'Control panel PSU Voltage:',
        'PU UPS accumulator:',
        'PU PCB temp.:',
        'Heat Distributor, PCB temp.:',
        'Flowmaster PSU voltage:',
        'Flowmaster pcb temp.:',
        'Surge protector:',
        'Smartstarter last error.:'
    ))
}

selector_title = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('td')            
incident_type_number = 0
get_cell = data_frame_main_call_screen.iat
driver_elem_by_x_path = driver.find_element_by_xpath
time_start = time.perf_counter() 

for k, (elem, next_elem) in enumerate(zip(selector_title, selector_title[1:])):
    t0, t1 = elem.text, next_elem.text

    try:
        i = lookup_table[t0]
    except KeyError:
        pass
    else:
        get_cell[j, i] = str(t1)
    
    if t0 == 'Smartstarter last error.:':
        incident_start_index = k+2

    get_cell[0,22]=driver_elem_by_x_path('//*[@id="callInfo"]').text[0:10]
    get_cell[0,23]=driver_elem_by_x_path('//*[@id="callInfo"]/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td').text
```

(I'm not sure what the purpose is of your last two lines of code, but it looks like there might be a bug there, since you're changing the value of the same cell in every iteration of the loop.)

---

As the comments say, though, the loop is probably not the thing slowing you down. Two suggestions, which you may or may not have thought of:

1. Web-scraping with `requests`/`beautifulsoup` is usually faster than with `selenium` (good tutorial [here](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter12/#calibre_link-378)). `requests` also takes more kindly to a multi-threaded approach, which could speed you up a *lot* for web-scraping. I guess it might not be possible to use `requests` if the data on the website is dynamically loaded, though — not sure.
2. I'm assuming you're using a `pandas` DataFrame, in which case mutating the DataFrame in every iteration of the loop can be very inefficient. If it's possible, it would probably be better to store the values in a standard Python `list`, and then update the `pandas` DataFrame all at once when the loop is complete. Some good info on what works well with pandas can be found [here](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6) — pandas can be very fast if you take advantage of the optimisations built into the package, but often will not respond kindly to a for-loop.

Comment: Thanks, this all super helpful I'll give that a go!

Comment: Your approach got it down to 6.5s, thanks again

Comment: 180s down to 6.5s?? Fantastic, glad I could help!!